# How to make variable array of string and assign it an array from argument

Tags: java, android

I don't know what term to be used for this scenario, but this is what I want.

```
socket.on("user-joined", args1 -> {
  String param1 = args1[0];
  String param2 = args1[1];
  args1[2];  <-- this is an array and i want to make a for loop from this param and log each content.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `args1` is an Object array, you should cast first the position 2 to tell the compiler that the object stored in that position is an array of Strings.

You could try this:

```
socket.on("user-joined", args1 -> {
  String param1 = args1[0].toString(); // This is necessary becase args1 is an object array
  String param2 = args1[1].toString(); // This is necessary becase args1 is an object array

  // Suposing args1 is an array of Object
  for(String s : (String[]) args1[2]) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
  // Or using streams
  Arrays.stream((String[]) args1[2]).forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

Instead of calling `System.out.println` you can use the logging system you need.